# DataTables Clickable Row Links from Server Side JSON

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable where I had been loading all the data at once, but my dataset is going to end up being very large so I decided to move everything server side.

Previously I was able to embed links into each row by using a "data-url" attribute then listening for a click with this function:

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var url = this.getAttribute("data-url")
        window.open(url, "_self");
    });
```

It worked perfectly like that, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work using AJAX and JSON.

My JSON response looks like this:

```
 {"recordsFiltered": 1, "recordsTotal": 6, 
 "data": [{"4": "", "6": "", "7": "Online", "3": "", "DT_RowClass": "success",
 "5": "", "data-url": "/relative-url/pk/", "2": "TestType2", 
 "0": "Test", "1": "ABCD"}], "draw": "11"}
```

However I'm not sure how I get DataTables to add the data-url attribute to the row. I've been scouring the documentation to try to find an example of this use case, but haven't had any luck so far.

If there isn't a built in functionality, I imagine that I will need to override the function DataTables uses to load in the JSON data, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm much better with my server side language than javascript so I really appreciate more specific answers if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @cjungel above that's one way to do it. Mor recent versions of DataTable use [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) though. So for example you could use this type of thing:

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, index){
    $(row).attr("data-url", data[1]);
}
```

As per this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/m6q4jc4j/1/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. I had to change my JSON response "data-url" to "8", because it wasn't in data list for that function. Afterwards I was able to retrieve it perfectly using your example with the index adjusted.

Comment: According to docs [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) is more efficient for this.

Comment: Thanks, @Gyrocode.com I should have read the documentation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fnCreatedRow` callback.

According to the [documentation](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnCreatedRow):

> This function is called when a TR element is created (and all TD child
>   elements have been inserted), or registered if using a DOM source,
>   allowing manipulation of the TR element (adding classes etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up going with annoyingmouse's answer since I found it easier, but I do appreciate the method you suggested as well.